# Find all of .exe files in program files folder

Tags: c++, winapi

I am looking for something that help with my code. I just want to analyse my program files folder on windows and print all of `.exe` files in this folder. I wrote something but I need some help and after that I'll make the `.exe` files to button but this is not my challenge right now the first part is my issue :)

```cpp
int dirListFiles(char* startDir)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA  wfd;
    char path[MAX_PATH];

    sprintf(path, "%s\\*", startDir);

    std::string fileName;
    std::string s_path = startDir;
    std::string fullPath;

    fprintf(stdout, "In Directory \"%s\"\n\n", startDir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFileA(path, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("FindFirstFIle failed on path = \"%s\"\n", path);
        abort();
    }

    BOOL cont = TRUE;
    while (cont == TRUE)
    {
        if ((strncmp(".", wfd.cFileName, 1) != 0) && (strncmp("..", wfd.cFileName, 2) != 0))
        {
            if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                sprintf(path, "%s\\%s", startDir, wfd.cFileName);
                dirListFiles(path);
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = wfd.cFileName;
                fullPath = s_path + "\\" + fileName;

                std::string fileExt = PathFindExtensionA(fullPath.c_str()); //the big"A"in PathFindExtensionA is very important :)((()
                if (fileExt == ".exe")
                {
                    std::cout << fileExt << std::endl;
                 
                }
            }
            cont = FindNextFileA(hFind, &wfd);
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}

int main()
{

    return 0; //this part is not very important for me right now
}
```

Comment: @user:9305398 thanks for edit

Comment: I know it's connected to "find first file" and "find next file" but I exactly don't know how

Comment: FindNextFile & FindClose are not in the good place. Full paths can be greater than MAX_PATH (only segments are limited to MAX_PATH). Also why don't you use unicode functions? File path are Unicode on Windows. This should work: https://pastebin.com/raw/rm7wNiZE

Comment: at least leave comment when you are giving negative

Comment: `int main() { return 0; }` is overly verbose. If you want a program that does nothing `int main() {}` is perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working very well

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATAA  wfd;

int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

int dirListFiles(const char* startDir)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA  wfd;
    char path[MAX_PATH];

    sprintf(path, "%s\\*", startDir);

    std::string fileName;
    std::string s_path = startDir;
    std::string fullPath;

    //fprintf(stdout, "In Directory \"%s\"\n\n", startDir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFileA(path, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("FindFirstFIle failed on path = \"%s\"\n", path);
        //abort();
    }

    BOOL cont = TRUE;
    while (cont == TRUE)
    {
        if ((strncmp(".", wfd.cFileName, 1) != 0) && (strncmp("..", wfd.cFileName, 2) != 0))
        {
            if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                counter2++;
                sprintf(path, "%s\\%s", startDir, wfd.cFileName);
                dirListFiles(path);
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                fileName = wfd.cFileName;
                fullPath = s_path + "\\" + fileName;

                std::string fileExt = PathFindExtension(fullPath.c_str());
                if (fileExt == ".exe")
                {
                    std::cout << fileName << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        cont = FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd);
    }

    FindClose(hFind);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* myfuckingstr = argv[1];

    dirListFiles(myfuckingstr);

    std::cout << "Counts: " << counter2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

just don't give a fake negative
test it and the leave command;)

Comment: and this is not just for program files it can scan most of the files